# JList highlight with jbutton

Tags: java, swing, highlight, jlist

i coded a little annotator in Java with a simple GUI based on Swing but i faced with a problem that is freaking me out.
The problem is: i have a jlist and two jbuttons modifying such jlist, the two buttons have the SAME listener but they don't work the same.
All it's supposed to work like this: once you select a row in the jlist you can tag it as ON TOPIC or OFF TOPIC (with the two buttons), the row changes color and then selects the next row but; even if the selection is on the right row (the next one) it highlights the next just for the OFF Topic button, why?

Here's the code:

```
public class TweetsAnnotator {

static Boolean[] annotations = null;
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
static JList jl;
static JButton offbutton = new JButton("OFF Topic");
static JButton onbutton = new JButton("ON Topic");
static String file = "inception_TweetList";

public TweetsAnnotator() {
}

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 * @throws FileNotFoundException 
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    // Read Tweets from file
    ObjectInputStream load = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) load.readObject();
    load.close();
    System.out.println(list.size() + " Tweets read from: " + file);

    // Check and read annotations
    File fileannot = new File(file + "Annotations");
    if (fileannot.exists()) {
        System.out.println("esiste, leggo");
        ObjectInputStream loadannot = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file + "Annotations"));
        annotations = (Boolean[]) loadannot.readObject();
        loadannot.close();
    } else {
        System.out.println("non esiste, creo poi leggo");
        ObjectOutputStream save = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file + "Annotations"));
        Boolean[] creatannotations = new Boolean[list.size()];
        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            creatannotations[i] = (Boolean) null;
        }
        save.writeObject(creatannotations);
        save.close();
        ObjectInputStream loadannot = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file + "Annotations"));
        annotations = (Boolean[]) loadannot.readObject();
        loadannot.close();
    }
    System.out.println(annotations.length + " Annotations loaded");     

    // Buttons
    offbutton.setActionCommand("off");
    offbutton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    offbutton.setEnabled(false);
    onbutton.setActionCommand("on");
    onbutton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    onbutton.setEnabled(false);

    // ButtonPanel
    JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
    buttonPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    buttonPane.add(onbutton);
    buttonPane.add(offbutton);

    // JList
    jl = new JList((Object[])list.toArray());
    jl.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    jl.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    jl.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
    jl.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
    ListSelectionListener listSelectionListener = new ListSelectionListener() {

        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if (e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false) {
                if (jl.getSelectedIndex() == -1) {
                    //No selection, disable buttons.
                    onbutton.setEnabled(false);
                    offbutton.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    //Selection, enable buttons.
                    onbutton.setEnabled(true);
                    offbutton.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    jl.addListSelectionListener(listSelectionListener);

    // JScrollPane
    JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(jl);

    // JFrame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(file);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowCloseHandler());

    // Add and show
    frame.getContentPane().add(listScroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

private static class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {   

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent( JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus ) {   
        Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent( list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus );   
        if ( annotations[index] == null ) {   
            c.setBackground( Color.white );   
        }   
        else if (annotations[index] == true) {   
            c.setBackground( Color.green );   
        } else {
            c.setBackground( Color.red);
        }
        return c;   
    } 
}

private static class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int ind = jl.getSelectedIndex() +1;
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("on")) {
            System.out.println("ON");
            annotations[jl.getSelectedIndex()] = true;
        }
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("off")) {
            System.out.println("OFF");
            annotations[jl.getSelectedIndex()] = false;

        }
        jl.clearSelection();
        jl.setSelectedIndex(ind);
    }
}

private static class WindowCloseHandler extends WindowAdapter {

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
        ObjectOutputStream save = null;
        try {
            save = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file + "Annotations"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            save.writeObject(annotations);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            save.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Saved.");
    }
}
}
```

Even though jl.requestFocus(); works fine, i tried another thing that make it works: i swapped these two lines

```
buttonPane.add(onbutton);
buttonPane.add(offbutton);
```

but, why?
Sorry if i ask again but it's really strange, isn't it?

Comment: I'd suggest to edit and post code without FileIO, nobody have got your File, then no idea why bothering with that, meaning with hardcoded value for Swing JCOmponents, the question could be answerable,

Comment: Consider using a `JCheckBox` or having `JRadioButton` instances in a button group instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your cell render, try this instead

```
if (annotations[index] == null) {
    //c.setBackground(Color.white);
} else if (annotations[index] == true) {
    c.setBackground(Color.green);
} else {
    c.setBackground(Color.red);
}
```

For something a "little" extended, you could also try

```
private static class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Border SELECTION_BORDER = new LineBorder(UIManager.getColor("List.selectionBackground"));
    private static final Border EMPTY_BORDER = new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1);

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        setBorder(EMPTY_BORDER);
        if (annotations[index] == null) {

            if (isSelected) {

                setBorder(SELECTION_BORDER);

            }

            c.setBackground(Color.white);
        } else if (annotations[index] == true) {
            c.setBackground(Color.green);
        } else {
            c.setBackground(Color.red);
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Basically, what you are doing is changing the selection highlight color, hiding the selection.  As to why you did get a paint artifact that "seemed" to highlight the selected row is still a slight mystery to me :P

**UPDATED with Knowing why**

The paint artifact you are sometimes getting is a result of the `hasFocus` parameter of the cell renderer, painting a focus rectangle.

Now, if you want to keep your existing cell renderer, then try this in the ActionEvent

```
 //jl.clearSelection();
 jl.setSelectedIndex(ind);
 jl.requestFocus();
```

From what I can tell, it seems to a slight qwerk with the repaint manager.  If I added `jl.repaint()` into you existing code (under the `setSelectedIndex` call) I can get it to never paint the focus rectangle :P

Comment: Ok, it works with the jl.requestFocus(); solution but i read that this method si discouraged. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I see, you could use the recommended requestFocusInWindow method instead

Answer (score 2):

not solving your quesion, not solved something, never to runs your code, just split that to the logics blocks, add minimum required rulles, sorry up-to 5 minutes

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class TweetsAnnotator {

    private Boolean[] annotations = null;
    private JList jl;
    private JButton offbutton = new JButton("OFF Topic");
    private JButton onbutton = new JButton("ON Topic");
    private String file = "inception_TweetList";
    private ArrayList<String> list;
    private ObjectInputStream load;
    private ObjectInputStream loadannot;
    private ObjectOutputStream save;

    public TweetsAnnotator() {// Read Tweets from file
        loadDatas();
        offbutton.setActionCommand("off"); // Buttons
        offbutton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        offbutton.setEnabled(false);
        onbutton.setActionCommand("on");
        onbutton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        onbutton.setEnabled(false);
        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel(); // ButtonPanel
        buttonPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        buttonPane.add(onbutton);
        buttonPane.add(offbutton);
        jl = new JList(list.toArray()); // JList
        jl.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        jl.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
        jl.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
        jl.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
        ListSelectionListener listSelectionListener = new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if (e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false) {
                    if (jl.getSelectedIndex() == -1) {
                        onbutton.setEnabled(false); //No selection, disable buttons.
                        offbutton.setEnabled(false);
                    } else {
                        onbutton.setEnabled(true); //Selection, enable buttons.
                        offbutton.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        jl.addListSelectionListener(listSelectionListener);
        JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(jl); // JScrollPane
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(file); // JFrame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowCloseHandler());
        frame.add(listScroller, BorderLayout.CENTER); // Add and show
        frame.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void loadDatas() {
        try {
            load = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            list = (ArrayList<String>) load.readObject();
            System.out.println(list.size() + " Tweets read from: " + file);
            File fileannot = new File(file + "Annotations"); // Check and read annotations
            if (fileannot.exists()) {
                System.out.println("esiste, leggo");
                loadannot = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file + "Annotations"));
                annotations = (Boolean[]) loadannot.readObject();
                loadannot.close();
            } else {
                System.out.println("non esiste, creo poi leggo");
                save = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file + "Annotations"));
                Boolean[] creatannotations = new Boolean[list.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    creatannotations[i] = (Boolean) null;
                }
                save.writeObject(creatannotations);
                loadannot = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file + "Annotations"));
                annotations = (Boolean[]) loadannot.readObject();
            }
            System.out.println(annotations.length + " Annotations loaded");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(" Something wrong happened");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(" Something wrong happened");
        } finally {
            if (load != null) {
                try {
                    load.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
            if (save != null) {
                try {
                    save.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
            if (loadannot != null) {
                try {
                    loadannot.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Load block ended");
    }

    private class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            if (annotations[index] == null) {
                c.setBackground(Color.white);
            } else if (annotations[index] == true) {
                c.setBackground(Color.green);
            } else {
                c.setBackground(Color.red);
            }
            return c;
        }
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int ind = jl.getSelectedIndex() + 1;
            if (e.getActionCommand().equals("on")) {
                System.out.println("ON");
                annotations[jl.getSelectedIndex()] = true;
            }
            if (e.getActionCommand().equals("off")) {
                System.out.println("OFF");
                annotations[jl.getSelectedIndex()] = false;
            }
            jl.clearSelection();
            jl.setSelectedIndex(ind);
        }
    }

    private class WindowCloseHandler extends WindowAdapter {

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
            ObjectOutputStream save = null;
            try {
                save = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file + "Annotations"));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                save.writeObject(annotations);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                save.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Saved.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TweetsAnnotator tweetsAnnotator = new TweetsAnnotator();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, i'm sorry for my awful code but i was just making some tryouts. Thanks for tyding the mess, of course it wasn't answerable.

Comment: @user1575815 add expected value for JList's Items and edit your question without FileIO blocks, then somebody can to help you with GUI and Renderer or Action from JButton, otherwise everything could be shots to the dark :-)